# How do you play an audio file on keyboard keystroke?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-audio

I'm developing a space based environment in Rails 4 and want to play a small sound file every time a key is pressed while the user is filling out a form. In other words, every keystroke would make a small clicking sound while typing.

I'm also looking to have this solution hosted remotely possibly in the assets folder, so the user does not have to install some third party application or software to make it happen.

Is this even possible with rails? Or, what other frameworks/libraries/technologies would I need to incorporate to accomplish this with Rails, and any examples or links to examples would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rails is a server-side technology. Keyboards are client-side. You need something client-side to make the sounds which can detect the keystrokes. I'd suggest looking at triggering audio with javascript.

Comment: I am note sure. but i think it can help you http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/template/

Comment: Jon, I don't know how I missed seeing your point and solution, as your logic is obvious and sound. I think you're right on the money there. 
And userxyz, from poking around, I might be able to make that solution work, I'll certainly give it a try and update the post if I get it to work. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I was able to get the solution to work like a charm using both Jon's and userxyz's suggestions. Specifically using Javascript's onkeypress event to fire a soundmanager function. Thanks!

Comment: could you post your solution? I am also interested in this.

Comment: ardochhigh, please find deployment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Sound Manager -->  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/soundman/demo/360-player/360player.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/soundman/demo/flashblock/flashblock.css" />       
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="/soundman/demo/360-player/script/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->                 


<!-- I'm not certain which of the following .js includes are actually required, I included them all and it works, however, some of these includes may not be necessary for the most basic of implementations. Please update if you find the minimal required includes -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/soundman/demo/360-player/script/berniecode-animator.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soundman/script/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soundman/demo/360-player/script/360player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">soundManager.setup({url: '/soundman/swf/'});</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hoverCategory() {
    soundManager.setup({
      url: '/soundman/demo/_mp3/hover01.wav',
      onready: function() {
        var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
          id: "a2", // <----------- Make this unique or you might run into conflicts
          url: '/soundman/demo/_mp3/hover01.wav'    //  <------- mp3's work as well 
        });
        mySound.play(); // <------------- lots of cool options on mySound, play() being just one of them
      },
      ontimeout: function() {
      }
    });
}

</script>

<!-- Onclick -->
<%= f.check_box :radial, :onclick => "Javascript:hoverCategory()" %> 

<!-- Onmouseover -->
<%= f.submit :onmouseover => "Javascript:hoverCategory()" %>

<!-- Onkeypress -->
<%= f.text_field :status, :onkeypress => "Javascript:hoverCategory()" %>
```